# How to execute a bat file on a different machine and fetch the output in Java

Tags: java, rmi

I need to execute a Windows `.bat` file on a different machine. I know :

1. the IP address of the remote machine, and
2. the executable file location.

How do I execute that particular file and how can I get its output?

Both the machines run Windows.

I already saw these links:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/rmi/hello/hello-world.html
http://www.onezerozeroone.eu/html/rmi_howto.html

But I am still not very clear on how to start?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this just using Java and RMI.

For obvious reasons, there isn't a way of running code on a remote machine unless that machine is set up to allow that sort of access. Otherwise, anyone could run anything on your machine at any time!

If it's a `.bat` file that you want to run, then you should look at setting up something like an ssh server on the other machine. That way, your machine will be able to connect to it via ssh (using a Java library if you like), execute the `.bat` file, and capture the output.

But if it doesn't need to be a `.bat` file, and you just want some of your own code to be triggered on the remote machine, you could write a (Java) application to run on the remote machine and listen on a particular port for messages instructing it on what to calculate, and then return the results.

That is pretty much the standard pattern for all remote services, including web servers.

Comment: Actually there are lots of servers(say 4 ), and I need to develop a web app  which displays the status, if the server is up or not. And allows starting and stopping the servers, etc. I am using Java for this. So how can I achieve this?